Unable to add autostart to tauri
npm run tauri add autostart

 > aw-tauri@0.0.0 tauri
 >tauri add autostart

error: unrecognized subcommand 'add'

I am unable to add autostart to my Tauri project. I have tried upgrading to the latest Tauri and reading the docs. No help!

check the current version of your tauri-cli by running cargo tauri --version
if the version is below 2.0, try to upgrade tauri-cli to version 2 by running cargo install tauri-cli --version "^2.0.0-beta"
be aware upgrading from version 1 to 2 could introduce breaking changes to other parts of your project.
Reference: https://v2.tauri.app/reference/cli/#add

Update package.json -> devDependencies -> @tauri-apps/cli to version ^2.1.0

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
